# Using Go race flag on windows. Which gcc I need to make it work?

Tags: windows, go, gcc

When I try to enable golang's race durring build or test it always fails and within output I see this:

```
crt2(.rdata$.refptr.__ImageBase): relocation target __ImageBase not defined
```

I've tried cygwin and this one -> https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases but without luck so far. Do you have any idea which gcc for windows works, Maybe I need change something in Go's env, gcc settings or something like that?

Example:
without gcc:

```
go build -race
runtime/cgo(.text): relocation target __mingw_vfprintf not defined
runtime/cgo(.text): relocation target __acrt_iob_func not defined
runtime/cgo(.text): relocation target __mingw_vfprintf not defined
runtime/cgo(.text): relocation target __acrt_iob_func not defined
```

with gcc from https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases

```
go build -race
crt2(.rdata$.refptr.__ImageBase): relocation target __ImageBase not defined
```

with mingw-18.0-without-git.exe from https://nuwen.net/mingw.html I get:

```
go build -race
crt2(.text): relocation target GetStartupInfoA not defined
libmsvcrt(.rdata$.refptr.__imp__acmdln): relocation target _acmdln not defined
```

so something is always missing. :)

Comment: https://www.mingw-w64.org/

Comment: @JimB already tried that, doesn't work :)

Comment: That is the commonly supported port of gcc, so you need to show a [mre] and explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: @JimB
Here you go:
without gcc:
go build -race
runtime/cgo(.text): relocation target __mingw_vfprintf not defined
runtime/cgo(.text): relocation target __acrt_iob_func not defined
runtime/cgo(.text): relocation target __mingw_vfprintf not defined
runtime/cgo(.text): relocation target __acrt_iob_func not defined

with gcc from https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases
go build -race
crt2(.rdata$.refptr.__ImageBase): relocation target __ImageBase not defined

Comment: Please update the question rather than insert blocks of output and code into the comments. are you using the latest release of Go and gcc? Did you try reading through the GithHub issues about this error? https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23649

Comment: https://www.msys2.org/